# Why do I keep getting the following error : "Unable to resolve module @react-navigation-stack"?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am building a project in React Native with `expo`. I keep getting the same error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq6Xh.png)

Here's my `App.js`:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';    
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation-stack';
import Home from './src/components/Home.js';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function myStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Sreen 
      name="Home" 
      component={Home}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <myStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here's a little part of my `package.json`:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/core": "react-navigation/core",
    "@react-navigation/native": "react-navigation/native",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
},
```

Could you please help me understand why I keep getting this error even though I installed `react-navigation-stack`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please read the instructions for `react-navigation` v4.x, [react-navigation-stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator).

Remove the **@** sign and you need to use it like this:

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

And to Install please run the below cmd for `expo`:

> expo install react-navigation-stack

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Why suggest someone to use an older version when they are already using the new API? The proper fix it to use correct package name, not use older version and rewrite all usage.

Comment: He is already using the 4.x version, didn't recommend anything here, it's just a fix that I mentioned.

Comment: As per their code, they are not. Even if they have it in package.json. Regardless, they are starting a new project from the looks of it, recommending an older version of the library for new projects isn't great. It'll only confuse them in future.

Answer (score -1):

You typed the package name wrong. It's `@react-navigation/stack`, not `@react-navigation-stack`

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/ for installation and usage.